# Laravel 5.3. - how to use sum('column') from relation in where clause and orderBy it

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, sum, relation

I have two tables: users and user_actions. I need to get all users where('available', true) (...and some other logic) and order them by sum of user_actions.clicks column.

```
public function actions()
{
        return $this->hasMany(UserActions::class);
}
```

I need something like this:

```
User::where('available', true)->where("something else....")->orderBy('sum(user_actions.clicks)', 'desc')->get();
```

The result must be a Collection of User class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `DB::raw` in the `orderBy` as:

```
User::where('available', true)
    ->where("something else....")
    ->join('user_actions', 'users.id', '=', 'user_actions.user_id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("sum('user_actions.clicks')"))
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->select('users.*')
    ->get();
```

Or you could use `sortBy` methods of the collection as:

```
User::where('available', true)->with('user_actions')->get()
    ->sortBy(function ($user) {
        return $user->user_actions->sum('clicks');
    });
```

Generally, you can handle this all on the at database end but this way is worth it because it greatly simplifies the process.

Comment: thanks, this was my first solution too, but if I use join, I get this error: "Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'compari_ci.users.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY ..." created_at is just another field in users table. I'm using Laravel 5.3 btw.

Comment: This is related to MySQL. Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: If I do this, I only get the sum value, and no user attributes: `$query->join('user_actions', 'user_actions.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                    $query->selectRaw('sum(user_actions.clicks) as clicks');
                    $query->groupBy('user_id');
                    $query->orderBy('clicks', 'desc');`

Comment: so you are suggesting to groupBy all user fields? this doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: Or you can try this solution https://mattstauffer.co/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: If i set strict to false, I don't get any more errors about group by, but it does't apply the ordering. The query looks right to me: `select users.* from users inner join user_actions on users.id = user_actions.user_id where available = true group by properties.id order by sum('user_actions.clicks') desc`

Comment: It actually works with strict, the ordering is applied, I had to many ' in the query: `$query->orderBy(DB::raw("sum(**'user_actions.clicks'**)"), 'desc');`It should be: `$query->orderBy(DB::raw("sum(**user_actions.clicks**)"), 'desc');` . So setting strict to false works for me. Thanks @iCode

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
->selectRaw('user_actions.clicks, sum(user_actions.clicks) as clicks')
->where('available', true)->where("something else....")
->orderBy('clicks', 'desc');
```

Comment: Without grouping by users.id you will get only one row with a `SUM` of all clicks.